# Android toolbar searchView too wide to move other items

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

`SearchView` always expanded will move other items out off screen, but if set `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` it will be normal.

I want to build a `toolbar` like facebook app.

There are two conditions:

1. Three item: `searchView` & other two items
2. Keep expanded

I had done both, but the items not in the correct position.
[image: problem position]

This is correct position (but I want it Keep expanded):
[image: correct position]

Here is my code:

layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/tool_search_hint"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/tool_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_user"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"
        android:title="@string/tool_user"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_actions, menu);

    MenuItem menuSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuSearchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use searchView.setMaxWidth(400).